# Pourquoi le badge « Strunk & White » est-il appelé ainsi ? — Why is the “Strunk & White” badge called “Strunk & White”?

Tags: discussion, badges

*Strunk* n'est pas référencé dans les dictionnaires, ce serait apparemment un mot connu en allemand.

- Quelle est l'origine du mot, sa traduction et son emploi habituel ?
- Il est décerné à celles et ceux qui ont *édité plus de 80 posts*, y a-t-il donc une expression *Strunk & White* en rapport avec ce thème ?

---

"Strunk" is not in any dictionary, but it's apparently known in German.

- What is the origin of the word, its translation and its usual usage?
- The badge is awarded to those who have edited 80 posts, so is there a "Strunk & White" expression related to editing?

Comment: @Laure provided a brief explanation, but this not the same as translation; for this site to work, we need to be able to guarantee that English speakers are able to understand all meta posts. Unfortunately, the conversation which has continued via comments since my translation request serves only to fracture the community. I'm closing this question. In the future, you may make meta posts in French, but only if you translate them in their entirety.

Comment: @AnaHevesi Please **do not close support questions just because they're posted in French**. It's bad enough that we lack a French user interface; we need to have a support channel where users can ask questions in French. Given that the question is of little interest to English speakers, I think the level of translation provided here is sufficient. If you want a more complete translation, feel free to request it, but do not close the question. We do routinely provide full English translations to questions that may involve Stack Exchange staff.

Comment: @AnaHevesi Cette question a d'abord été posée sur le site *French Language* et déplacée ici parce que j'y ai mentionné sa source. A mon sens elle aurait dû y rester car elle fait le lien entre deux ouvrages de références culturelles que l'on ne peut trouver dans les dictionnaires. Je ne suis pas assez calé en anglais pour la traduire correctement.

Comment: @Gilles, closing the question was a misplaced attempt on my part to stop the flow of comments, since they were adding to the amount of context which would need to be translated. I simply hadn't realized closing doesn't prevent comments and was happy to reopen once translation was complete via a new question. In the future we will continue to ask that all French meta posts get translated, but closure isn't necessary. Sorry for the misfire.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

William **Strunk**, Jr. & Elwyn Brooks **White** ont écrit un ouvrage de référence sur la langue anglaise consulté par un grand nombre de personnes quand dans le doute sur ce qui peut/doit se dire, et qui continue à être réédité après la mort de leurs auteurs.

L'ouvrage est parfois désigné par le nom de ses auteurs (le *Strunk & White*) plutôt que par son nom (*The Elements of Style*).

Comment: Minor nit: Strunk and White didn't write the book together. Strunk wrote the first version in 1919; E. B. White (one of Strunk's former students) didn't revise it until 1957, 11 years after Strunk's death. Strunk & White is still well known in the English-speaking world, especially in the USA but is not well regarded by linguists, who ridicule its over-prescriptive stance.